# Logging framework inside a managed package

Tags: logging

I really don't have much idea of how logging works in a managed package context. So my question might be very basic to you.

Can anybody suggest a logging framework which we can use for our managed package? The logging framework should be such that it shouldn't print out our debug logs for any customer who have installed our app. If and only if the user in a subscriber org allows us to debug an issue, then only it will start printing the logs, or dumps the logs in a custom object.

I have heard about rflib, but not sure whether this will server the purpose: https://github.com/j-fischer/rflib

Comment: here's another one: https://github.com/afawcett/eventlogging

Answer (score 0):

[Logs aren't exposed to the subscriber by default](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_debugging_sub_org.htm)

If you are considering sending logging information to a custom object I think there would always be a risk that the subscriber could enable that mode on their own & be able to see the logs.

Either way be careful to not log [sensitive information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_storing_sensitive_data.htm). That could result in a failure during security review.

Another nice criteria to add to your framework search would be serializing objects only if logging is enabled. Great performance boost!